# SQL Joins not giving correct sql output

Tags: sql, left-join

I have following table structure

> `Department` (**`deptID`**, `deptName`)
>
> `DepartmentTask` (**`deptID`, `taskCode`**, `taskName`)
>
> `DepartmentTaskInMajorTask` (**`deptID`, `taskCode`**, `T1`, `T2`, … `Tn`)

I need the following columns as the output

```
deptName, taskName, T1, T2, …Tn
```

I have tried a few joins but I am getting multiple values, not sure how I do that. For example, `deptID = ‘xyz’` has 10 tasks, hence table `DepartmentTaskInMajorTask` has 10 rows. So, the output shold only return 10 rows. But when I tried, it gives me more than 10!

Following is the SQL I have tried:

```
SELECT Department.deptName, 
       MajorTask_DeptTaskRelation.T1, 
       MajorTask_DeptTaskRelation.T2, 
       DepartmentalTask.taskName
FROM DepartmentalTask 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Department ON DepartmentalTask.deptID = Department.deptID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN MajorTask_DeptTaskRelation ON Department.deptID = MajorTask_DeptTaskRelation.deptID
```

`DepartmentalTask` has 131 records, so does the `MajorTask_DeptTaskRelation`. So, the output should also give me 131 records with `deptName` and `taskName`.

Comment: Please elaborate which SQL statements you tried exactly.

Comment: can you paste the query that you are trying to execute?

Comment: Without seeing your SQL the discussion would be poinless.

Comment: daer post your code then we all will help you ok

Comment: and one thing when you make left join then you will get extra record if it have related record in the other table or not but when you make inner join then you just get the related record in the other table ok dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly I think you can try with a `INNER JOIN` query to retrieve records which have related records in other tables as follow

```
SELECT a.deptName, b.taskName, c.T1, c.T2, … c.Tn 
FROM Department a
INNER JOIN DepartmentTask b
ON a.deptID = b.deptID
INNER JOIN DepartmentTaskInMajorTask c
ON b.taskCode = c.taskCode
```

Please check this usefull post about visual explanation of sql join [**here**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: @user1889838 You welcome man! If you feel answer was correct and it helped you out please consider to accept it, so you will also help people in the future with similar problems.

Answer (score -1):

My best guess given the lack of detail in your question is a simple join to the other tables:

```
select deptName, taskName, T1, T2, ...Tn
from DepartmentTaskInMajorTask dtimt
join DepartmentTask dt on dt.deptID = dtimt.deptID
  and dt.taskCode = dtimt.taskCode
join Department d on d.deptID = dtimt.deptID
```